# other window show first when switch desktop

Tags: desktop, spaces, ui, animation

When switching desktop with four finger sliding, it seems windows that are assigned to all desktop appear first for a second and then shows the last focused window. Is it possible to skip the showing of those windows and show previous focus directly? Many of such windows could have a different color theme than the previous focused window, which hurts the eyes. Currently manual Cmd+w to close those windows works, but easily forgotten after use.